# QListView losing selection on edit

Tags: qt, qlistview, qsqltablemodel

I have a QListView pulling data from a QSQLTableModel.

Upon a user clicking an 'Add' button, I add a new item and open it for editing:

```
QSqlTableModel *tblModel= qobject_cast<QSqlTableModel *>(ui->listView->model());
if(tblModel->insertRow(tblModel->rowCount()))
    ui->listView->edit(tblModel->index(tblModel->rowCount()-1, 1));
```

But once the user is done editing the new value, the selection of listView is lost. I can't find a signal on QListView or QSQLTableModel to handle when and edit has finished for me to 'restore' the selection.

Is there a way I can make sure the selection is kept?

Answer (score 1):

An excerpt from edit() function documentation:

> Note that this function does not change the current index. Since the
>   current index defines the next and previous items to edit, users may
>   find that keyboard navigation does not work as expected. To provide
>   consistent navigation behavior, call setCurrentIndex() before this
>   function with the same model index.

Comment: Thanks, this does fix another niggling problem I had, but doesn't solve the problem I posted as once editing of the new item is finished (enter pressed or focus lost etc), the selection is reset.